# jquery selector not working in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have a problem where I have to skin a site without being able to change the HTML.

As a result, I'm having to do some things with JS I wouldn't normally do. Part of what I have to do is move a "default" image into a new position. This works on all browsers, including IE7, EXCEPT IE8. Ideas?

```
$(".carouselThumbWrap.carouselSelected").animate({ marginTop: hoverYPos }, 1);
```

The HTML looks like this:

```
<li assetUrl="art.png" class="carouselThumbWrap carouselSelected" assetType="image">blah</li>
```

The only thing I can think is that we have a race situation. The carouselSelected is assigned by some widget or another that I can't change and must not have appeared by the time my `document.ready` function has run. Ideas? Am I missing something?

Comment: agreed. the community is built around asking questions and voting for and tagging good answers.

Comment: sorry. i'm pretty new here and didn't know how to do that. done.

Comment: As it turns out, it looks like it might be an animate() bug. Still investigating. Changing the code to $(".carouselThumbWrap.carouselSelected").css("background", "white"); works on IE8...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was a race situation and this fixed it:

```
$($(".carouselThumbWrap")[0]).addClass("carouselSelected");
```

Answer (score 0):

buggy IE8 misbehaving, could you try something like:

```
$(".carouselThumbWrap").each(function() {
  if(this.hasClass("carouselSelected")) this.animate({ marginTop: hoverYPos }, 1);
});
```

to get round it?

Answer (score 0):

If it turns out to be a timing issue, you might be able to paper over the problem by using the [Live Query](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
$("li.carouselThumbWrap.carouselSelected").animate({ marginTop: hoverYPos }, 1);
```

It should be the same but if it is a bug in ie it might help.

Answer (score 0):

If some other JS function is also screwing with the carousel, you can overwrite the offending function with one of your own. Then in your new, overwritten function, call the original and also add your own logic to fix everything.

```
someWidget.badFunction = function()
{
    //mess up carousel so julie can get her work done
}

var originalBadFunction = someWidget.badFunction;

somewidget.badFunction = function()
{
    originalBadFunction();
    //put your code that fixes everything and makes the world right again here
}
```